# Why is WiFi on 100% of the time, even though Extended Standby Mode is enabled?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-s

My Sony Xperia S has an Extended Standby Mode which states that WiFi and mobile data are disabled after a time when the screen is off.

However, sometimes this stops working and the battery starts falling quickly, and BetterBatteryStats shows that WiFi was on 100% of the time for the last 22 hours. Usually after I reboot the phone it starts behaving normally.

This is the explanation text for the Extended Standby Mode:

[image]

And I know for sure that I don't have any downloads or uploads running.

What is happening here? How do I make sure that Extended Standby Mode really works?

Comment: Have you check the "Power Settings" or "Battery Settings" in the settings? It has it's own graph for showing when the Wi-Fi is enabled. Maybe BBS gives a false positive.

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović Unfortunately I've already plugged in my phone to the charger so the battery stats are reset. I'll need to wait until I can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings --> wifi
Press menu key or 3 dots
Tap on advanced 
Untick always scanning option.
And wifi will stay down when off

Comment: I can't find that option. There is only "Keep WiFi on during sleep", is that it?